# Validate the timezone of a string-formatted datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I need to confirm that a string-formatted datetime I receive is indeed in an expected timezone. The expected timezone is element from `pytz.all_timezones`, say "Europe/Brussels".
The input I get is in the format `2017-03-26T21:12:00+02:00`. I want to confirm that the input's timezone is Europe/Brussels.
Here's what I currently use, but I am not sure if it's the best/correct way.

```
import pytz 
from dateutil.parser import parse

input_dt = parse(datetime_str)
naive_input = input_dt.replace(tzinfo=None)

tz_expected = pytz.timezone("Europe/Brussels")

# apply the expected timezone to the naive datetime
input_in_expected_tz = tz_expected.localize(naive_input)

utc_offset_of_input = get_offset_from_utc(input_dt)
expected_utc_offset = get_offset_from_utc(input_in_expected_tz)
assert utc_offset_of_input == expected_utc_offset

def get_offset_from_utc(d):
    return d.utcoffset().seconds / (60 * 60)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What's p in `p.timezone`? Is it supposed to be `pytz.timezone`?

Comment: Be aware the problem as stated is not actually solvable.  While you can *verify* that the timestamp in question is a valid timestamp for the TZ, you cannot *confirm* that it is from that timezone, since there are possibly other timezones with the same offset.

Comment: @Charlie G - yes, my bad.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch - what matters is that the offset from UTC is correct and that after, say, one year if I want to convert back to the local timezone it will convert to the same `input_dt`, assuming that the UTC datetime and `expected_time_zone` are stored together.